# (Android) why wont float alpha work

Tags: android, transparency, alpha

I am trying to set an animator and have a button show up from transparent to percentage opaque.(like 70 % opaque). The problem is for some reason when i test it on the nexus one it does not show as it is supposed to. I even tried setting the alpha via xml to see if it is maybe the floats that don't work. Do i need to use some kind of modifier in xml like

```
android:alpha=".7f"
```

or anything similar because I am getting really frustrated that it doesnt work as it should.

also setting alpha with integers does work but it is not available with all the views.

Comment: did you tried like this: android:alpha="#88000000"

Comment: no but would something like that work in alpha animation fromalpha toAlpha?

Comment: no this does not work. i have tried it and the button just shows up no fade in. I dont know if it is the phone or the OS version.

Comment: For the fromAlpha toAlpha part i have found the error. I didnt put it into a set and it didnt work for some reason. setting alpha via xml does not work for me anywhere besides preview.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem once.

I was using this property in the parent layout:

```
animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

After I deleted this line the alpha worked again.

I hope this maybe will help someone.